# How to write data to a file from a listener in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to read in data from an analog input on an NI module and save it to a file.  Currently, I have this:

```
lh = listener(s0, 'DataAvailable', @save_to_file);
```

And my "save_to_file" function contains the following:

```
function save_to_file(~, event)

fileID = fopen('file.txt', 'a');

fprintf(fileID, event.Data);
fprintf(fileID, '\n');

fclose(fileID);

end
```

But upon completion of the script, the file is still empty.  I can't figure out what is wrong, whether it be in the listener, writing to the file, etc.  Does anyone notice an error in this code?

Comment: just for testing, try to display the `event.Data` in the `save_to_file` function. Also add a `disp('hey, I got here')` line in the beginning. That way you can see 1)if there is any data in the event, 2) if the function is ever being called.

Comment: Can you show us how you are triggering your event? `notify`?